# best way to store database details php

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql passwords Connecting to MySQL with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697928/mysql-passwords-connecting-to-mysql-with-php)

Okay so at the moment every time I need to connect to my mysql database, I have to hardcode all the parameters such as the server, user and pass which means if I ever change database details I'll have to go through dozens of scripts to change this info

I was just wondering if anyone could help me out by explaining how I can make a much more dynamic system to connect to my database

Thanks

Comment: Why would you connect to the DB separately each time? Connect once, store that connection in a variable, use that variable later on...

Comment: This is an _exact_ duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11697928/1415625 Please search first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, make connecting params like constants or defines, and store in confing as Tomdarkness said.

Answer (score 2):

A super simple solution to this would be to store your database details in a separate config file where you have variables defined for all your database connection details. You just include this file when you need to access these database details and reference the variables in this config file rather than using the actual details.